# How to change bpm of midi file using FL Studio?

Tags: midi, tempo, fl-studio

I recorded midi data in my DAW, FL Studio, with the incorrect tempo. How can I change tempo without affecting midi?

Comment: Changing the tempo will affect the midi, its playback speed the least.

Comment: You should be able to just change the tempo in the DAW and that should do it. Can you give us more details about the problem you are having and what you've tried so far?

Comment: related question: editing the midi file directly to change tempo. [How to edit a MIDI file's tempo settings](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/75005/how-to-edit-a-midi-files-tempo-settings).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really good demonstration of stretching Midi in FL:

1. Go to piano roll.

(2.) Adjust the snap settings.

3. Select all notes (or those you want to stretch) —> a little circle will appear on the right.

(4.) If needed, hold down the Alt key to bypass the "snap".

5. Drag the little circle to the position you need it. The notes' position and length will be adjusted to your needs.

More info:
https://howtomakeelectronicmusic.com/fl-studio-quick-tip-using-stretch-handle/