# How to directly edit a MIDI file's tempo settings

Tags: midi, tempo

How to edit the tempo of a MIDI file?
I have a .mid file; when opened it will play at a tempo of 60 BPM. I want to change that to 120.
Not that it plays faster at 120 BPM.

So 60 = 120

I try to find '60' with all kinds of text editors, to change that to 120. But I can't read the code (text).

Please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

A text editor will not help with this; you'd need a hex editor.
The thirteenth and fourteenth bytes in the file specify the number of ticks per quarter note (where "quarter note" does not necessarily correspond to a real quarter note, but is just a unit of time):

```
00000000: 4d 54 68 64 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 01 00 78 4d 54  MThd.........xMT
                                              ^^^^^
```

Double this value to double the playback speed. In this example, the new value would be 78<sub>16</sub> × 2 = F0<sub>16</sub>, i.e., `00 f0`.

---

It would be much easier to open and change the file in any MIDI sequencer.

Comment: This is the best answer to my question, now I know where to looke for and possible chances. Whitch midi sequencer could do this (the easy way)?

Comment: Any sequencer should be able to do this.